# Does millis() count from the start of the main program loop or the setup loop?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am writing code for an Arduino project that uses time to figure out the number of revolutions per minute. Just so I have an idea of the accuracy of my code, I am wondering if the `millis()` function starts counting the moment the Arduino is turned on, when it reaches the `setup()` `function`, or when the main program `loop()` starts? Anybody know which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter of `millis()` function starts from the start of your program, that means from the start of `void setup()` function.

Hope your confusion is solved.

Comment: does millis()  starts from the start of your program? I am not sure abt that.